RANCID types.base script location
Trying to create a custom script for my new ACI APIC controllers. The idea is to take backups of the running-config from one of the APICs. Therefore I created a new module. With that being said, I added also the APIC in the router-db and clogin files.

cisco-apic;script;rancid -t cisco-apic
cisco-apic;login;clogin
cisco-apic;module;aci
cisco-apic;inloop;aci::inloop
cisco-apic;command;aci::WriteTerm;show running-config

However I have been trying to find the script folder. For the life of me I have been unable to find it. Each module have their own script. Can anyone guide me on where this directory might be located?
A similar module with an existent script is for the NX-OS and is written as cisco-nx;script;rancid -t cisco-nx.
Someone that use RANCID, to identify the location of the script directory. The cisco-nx is loaded in all copies of RANCID.
